# How would I set up a smooth rotation for a angled object?

Tags: animation, objects, keyframes, blend-files

I'm trying to set up a rotation on the z axis for a angled crown on a model I have. [image: crown1]
I'm new to blender and have no idea how this would be done. I've set up a custom axis orientation but have no clue what to do after that. Would anyone be able to help? I've included the blend file.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### Setting up properly oriented origins for orientated objects with rotation applied.

After the orientation is lost, if there is the possibility of planar faces, it can easily be recreated.

1. Create a face, which is perpedicular to your desired orientation axis. <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> > <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> > <kbd>F</kbd>
2. Since my faces median is even at the desired center, I snap the *cursor to selected*. <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor To Selected*

[image]

3. Add a helper object, in my case a cube. <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Cube*

[image]

4. Apply all transformations of the helper cube.
5. Activate snapping and set it to *Closest Face*.

   - Snap ON
   - Faces
   - Closest
   - Align rotation ON
   - Project individual[ly] ON

[image]

6. Grab the cube <kbd>G</kbd> and by moving it onto the helper face, it will align itself.
7. Snap it to the cursor afterwards. <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Selection to Cursor*

[image]

8. Select the original object <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd>, then <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> select the helper object, and join them <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>. The will merge into one object which still holds the helper objects orientation.
9. Delete the unnecessary faces and vertices.

[image]